# Proof of failure of unique factorization of 4K+1

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

For the prime number in 4K+1, number 9, 21, and 49 are in the set of prime number.
But it’s uniqueness of factorization fail because 9*49=21*21.
What is the mathematic reason prove that 4K+1 fail the unique of factorization?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need other than that $9, 49,$ and $21$ are "prime" in the multiplicatively closed set you are calling $4K+1.$ One counter-example is all you need to prove it is not true.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, in the language of abstract algebra, they are irreducible but not prime (which is precisely why unique factorization fails).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yeah, that was why I put "prime" in quotes - but for the beginning number theorist, "prime" is the same as "irreducible."

Answer (score 1):

The numbers of the form $4k+1$ are missing some primes.  Hilbert introduced this example to show why the theory of ideals was needed in higher algebra.  T

At the heart of it, we're missing the $\gcd(9,21)$ and the $\gcd(49,21).$  In the ordinary integers, we aren't missing these numbers, but in Hilbert's system, they're not there and this is what causes the  non-uniqueness of factorization.  We can group the missing numbers in two different ways.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Aye.